# Temporarily storing output of shell commands to tmpfs

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'd like to be able to quickly open the output (both stdout and stderr) of the last 10 or so commands run in emacs. I still want to be able to see the output of these commands in my shell though. I am close but a little stuck.

I can stick `exec > >(tee "$HOME/tmp/out0") 2>&1` into my .zshrc which will both display the output of every command and append it to the file $HOME/tmp/out0. I've also mounted $HOME/tmp as a tmpfs so that it's fast and doesn't wear my disk down.

What I want to be able to do is on a shell command being excecuted move $HOME/tmp/out0 to $HOME/tmp/out1 and move that to $HOME/tmp/out2 and on and on until I delete $HOME/tmp/out9 (I only want to store 10 commands) then write the output to $HOME/tmp/out. Then I can alias e0..e9 to open emacsclient to the corresponding file.

I won't rule out the possibility of creating a buffer in emacs (running in server mode) and storing the output in emacs's memory. This is what I wanted to do originally but it seems much harder. I think the tmpfs is an easier route and more robust.

Is this possible or am I just insane?

Comment: I did some testing and found the following issue: By using `exec > >(tee "$HOME/tmp/out0") 2>&1` any output is redirected to the same, continously running `tee` process. This process opens `$HOME/tmp/out0` once at the very beginning, any output will go to this file handle. When moving `out0` to `out1`, the file handle moves with the file and now points to `out1`. When copying, output will accumulate in `out0`. If you delete `out0` it will not be recreated, unless a new `tee` is started. Also, concurrent shells with separate `tee` processes accessing the same file.